# How to redirect output of a subprocess to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have the following python script:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import os
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


time = (datetime.now()- timedelta(hours=6)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') 
#print time

path = sys.argv[1]

os.chdir(path + '/src/MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Samples')


cmd = "php -f ListOrders.php %s > response.xml" %(time)
print cmd
args = shlex.split(cmd)
p = subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()
respFile = open("response.xml")
respFile.close()

tree = ET.parse(path + '/src/MarketplaceWebServiceOrders/Samples/response.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

I want to redirect the output of the subprocess to the file `response.xml`. In the next step I want to parse the contents of `response.xml. So it must be closed before we can parse. But, after execution`response.xml`ends up being blank and I'm getting error in the line`tree = ET.parse(...)`. I also tried:

```
respFile = open("response.xml","w")

cmd = "php -f ListOrders.php %s > %s" %(time,respFile)
print cmd
args = shlex.split(cmd)
p = subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()
respFile.close()
```

This doesn't work either. Please can someone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` is a shell feature but Popen() does not use a shell by default. You should be able to fix by using a shell explicitely:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
```

However I'd advise not to use a shell (for better security) and write the contents to a file using pure Python:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
with file('response.xml', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(stdout)
```

Comment: With modern Python, `with open(file, 'w') as output: subprocess.run(shlex.split(args), stdout=output, check=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample which opens a file for writing/reading:

```
import subprocess

with open('out.txt', 'w+') as f:
    cmd = ['/bin/ls', '/']
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=f)
    p.communicate()

    # Read from the file
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()
```

Comment: With recent versions of Python, you should prefer `subprocess.check_output` or `subprocess.run`

Comment: This question is still getting hits by new visitors, who will almost certainly not be using Python 2. That's why I added a comment to guide them.